# Submit JQuery Form $.post() handle display message on success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form I am submitting with $.post() in jquery..

```
$.post("testpage.php", $("#payment-form").serialize())
```

The post works fine itself, but when the post is done and successful the page will do other stuff such as display a thank you message and stuff. I just need to where to put to call to display the message.I do not understand where it goes in terms of the success being returned from the post.

Comment: Come on man, you were already at the correct page of the jquery documentation.. Try to read a bit more the next time before asking your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a 3rd argument to .post() that is the "success" callback.  It is a function to call when the .post execution is successful.

```
$.post("testpage.php", $("#payment-form").serialize(), function() { alert('post was successful!')})
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Thank you! I read through the documentation, I just didnt understand how work with the successhandler. Thank you for clearing it up!

Answer (score 2):

In short, like this:

```
$.post("testpage.php", $("#payment-form").serialize(), function () {
    // Start partying here.
}).fail(function() {
    // Handle the bad news here.
})
```

Comment: "I'm sorry to say... your request is terminal."

Comment: `$.post()` doesn't have any error callback, you need to use `.fail()` or `.then(succes, error)` to handle it

Comment: @A.Wolff, you're right... My fingers assumed it wrong, check edit

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), like as follow:

```
// Create POST request
var paymentPost = $.post("testpage.php", $("#payment-form").serialize());

// Assigned deferred objects
// "data" refers to the data, preferably in JSON format, returned by testpage.php
paymentPost
.done(function(data) {
    // Success
    // e.g. display thank you message, redirect to a payment successful page...
})
.fail(function(data) {
    // If error
    // e.g. display error message(s)
})
.always(function() {
    // Will always fire as long as POST request is submitted and completed
});
```

p/s: It is important to note that jqXHR methods like `.success()` and `.error()` are deprecated. To prepare for their eventual removal, you should abide to the new nomenclature for deferred objects ;)

Comment: Interesting thank you for this! I really appreciate the explanation of the variety of options!

Comment: `.fail()` isn't deprecated but `.error()`, anyway +1 for usefull answer